# Start pixel of turtle python simulator

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

The turtle simulator is quite helpful for moving objects but the problem I am facing is that I don't know the pixel value of the screen where the 'turtle arrow' starts its drawing. Also, when it comes to drawing a circle, it becomes difficult to figure out the pixel coordinates of its centre. Here is an example of a code:

```
import turtle
ob = turtle.Turtle()
ob.right(100)       
#Where does the turtle start with its head (pixel coordinates)?
ob.circle(5)
#Now the turtle draws a circle with radius 5, but in which direction will it point at first?
#How do we figure out the centre of this circle?
```

Could someone please help me with these two problems?

PS: I am using python 3.10

Comment: You should provide a minimal code to illustrate your issue. If you have no clue how to start, I am sure there are dozens of tutorials on how to draw a circle with turtle.

Comment: I know how to draw a circle but we just give the radius as argument, right? How can its centre coordinates be found?

Comment: @mozway I've added the code

Comment: I don't remember exactly but either the center is the position of the turtle, or rather I think the turtle starts on the side of the circle. This means you can compute the position of the center (likely, you have to shift one radius on the appropriate direction before starting to draw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import turtle
ob = turtle.Turtle()
ob.right(100)
```

> Where does the turtle start with its head (pixel coordinates)?

Turtles start out at `(0, 0)`, the origin.  Since you didn't move the turtle, it's *head* is still over the origin.

```
ob.circle(5)
```

> Now the turtle draws a circle with radius 5, but in which direction will it point at first?

The turtle starts drawing the circle in whatever direction the turtle is currently pointing.  For a newly hatched turtle, that's 0 degrees which is *right* on the screen.  (Using mode `'logo'` changes this default.)

Since your turtle first turned to the right 100 degrees, it will start drawing at 260 degrees heading (360 - 100), slightly to the left of straight down (i.e. 270 degrees.)

> How do we figure out the centre of this circle?

If the circle was drawn with a newly hatched turtle, then the center would be at `(0, 5)`.  (To center the circle on `(0, 0)`, for example, we'd move `-5` (i.e. -radius) pixels in the Y direction.)

But your turtle started with a heading of 260 degrees.  And, by default, circles are drawn counter-clockwise.  So we'd expect the center of your circle to be near `(5, 0)`, where a 270 degree heading would draw it.  If we do the math, turning 90 degrees towards the center of the circle and projecting a 5 pixel line, we get:

```
from math import cos, sin, radians

print(5 * cos(radians(260 + 90)), 5 * sin(radians(260 + 90)))
```

With output:  4.92403876506104 -0.868240888334652

Similarly, we can also get the center position by doing:

```
ob.left(90)
ob.penup()
ob.forward(5)
print(ob.position())
```

With output:  (4.92,-0.87)

Comment: Thank you very much. The answer was quite detailed and helpful.